# Does GreenPlum with PXF support avro data with schema evolution

Tags: avro, greenplum

We have `user` data (avro files) validated and ingested into HDFS using Schema Registry(data keep on evolving) and using GreenPlum with PXF to access HDFS data. Created one external table and trying to query the HDFS data but getting error as,

```
warehouse=# select * from user;
ERROR:  Record has 151 fields but the schema size is 152  (seg1 slice1 192.168.1.17:6001 pid=6582)
CONTEXT:  External table user
warehouse=#
```

`user` HDFS files are ingested using different schema versions, and GreenPlum external table has been created with fields from all the schema versions.

Comment: Currently, schema evolution for Avro is not supported in PXF. We are looking into adding this functionality.

Comment: thanks @frankgh  for the information, and really appreciate your help!